# How to fix this grid for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-grid

I started a site with it https://codepen.io/balazs_sziklai/pen/mOwoLg and I just realized that it doesn't work on IE. I looked on the forum and changed one thing that seemed to work but I don't know what else to do.

I add

```
display: -ms-grid;


.grid-layout {
display: -ms-grid;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(180px, 1fr));
grid-gap: 10px;
grid-auto-rows: minmax(180px, auto);
grid-auto-flow: dense;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;


.grid-item {
padding: 1rem;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #929796;
background-color: #333;
border-radius: 5px;
&:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #424242;


`.span-2 {
grid-column-end: span 2;
grid-row-end: span 2;

.span-3 {
grid-column-end: span 3;
grid-row-end: span 4;
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is NOT a forum.

Comment: I suggest you refer these links that may be helpful to you. Ref: https://medium.com/@elad/supporting-css-grid-in-internet-explorer-b38669e75d66 and https://css-tricks.com/css-grid-in-ie-debunking-common-ie-grid-misconceptions/ If issue persists then I suggest you use the alternative of CSS grid for IE 11 browser.

Comment: When I couldn't do it, I switched to a portfolio...